# "box selection" and delete in a meshed 3D scanned file

Tags: selection-tools

I'm new to Blender and I have some problems to delete vertices.

I've made a scan with a kinect v2 and constructed a mesh with KinectFusion but the mesh has too many vertices/edges/faces.

I've looked several forums but I don't find how to remove the scan's "background".

I have done : Edit mode, B, select all the background, X, delete vertices. However, this only remove the "surface vertices" of my selection.

Is there a way such as "cube selection" or something like that to remove entirely a zone within the cube?

I want to remove everything that is in red.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. If those parts you'd like to delete are disconnected from the main one, in Edit mode you could select one vertice of each part and press Ctrl+L. Alternatively you could select them with Circle select or Lasso select, just make sure to disable Limit Selection To Visible or select in Wireframe shading mode, see https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/basics.html.

Comment: Thanks, It worked perfectly! Ctrl+L did not work, however:
edit mode + Wireframe + B + selecting + X + delete vertices worked perfectly.